# Nikon d5300 lcd turned on for 2 second and it stopped working

Tags: nikon-d5300

I cant use any button or anything's just a black screen . It showed some date amd time setting for 2 second and it got blacked can anyone help

Comment: Is the battery good?

Answer (score 3):

The clock setting should only appear if the internal battery is also dead.
This should recharge if you put a fully charged standard interchangeable battery in & leave it for two days.

The brief flicker implies your regular battery doesn't have charge, and has been either out of the camera body for a long period, or has been flat for a long period. Test if it holds charge after recharging; make sure it's not swollen.
The charger has a couple of simple indicator light modes to tell you if it's charging properly or if there's an error. See [Troubleshooting Nikon battery charger problems](https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/eu/BV_article?articleNo=000042541&configured=1&lang=en_GB)

Also see [Why am I required to input the date and time on D5100 after charging the battery?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103073/why-am-i-required-to-input-the-date-and-time-on-d5100-after-charging-the-battery) - I'm not certain if the 5300 uses the exact same internal battery.
This [iFixit teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nikon+D5100+Teardown/5271) makes me pretty sure it's not something I'd want to tackle myself.